# Client: While using tortoiseSVN my access to the server is forbidden, but I do have access when using a browser

Tags: ssl, svn, repository, configure, svn-checkout

I'm the one who is configuring the server.  It has a SVN+SSH as well as an SSL for the company who will be accessing it.  I am able to browse AND checkout repos.  The firewall has been configured to allow access to another company.  They can browse the repos in a browser, but they get an error message when trying to SVN check-out the repo.  Error message: "Access to 'https://servernameaddress/path/to/repo' forbidden".  Why would they be able to browse the repo in a web browser, but not be able to checkout using an SVN client?

Comment: Proxy settings? Maybe the Browser uses a proxy and tortoise does not.

Comment: Maybe the certificate is invalid? Does the Browser complain about the cert?

Answer (score 1):

Are they connecting to the internet via a proxy?

If they had a proxy configured in the browser perhaps Tortoise is not using this proxy.